# Sorting template array using std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting

```
#include <algorithm> 
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
 
int main() {
   
    std::array<int, 10> s{5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3};

    struct {
            bool operator()(int a, int b) const
            {   
                return a < b;
            }   
        } customLess;

    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), customLess);
    for (auto a : s) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }   

    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

I want to sort the array using std : : sort. The code above works fine, but when I try with template array in my main task (GArr<int, 5> arr{5, 2, 3, 4, 1};) the compiler gives the following

> error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'Iterator' and
> 'Iterator')|

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is `GArr`?  Please post a [mre].

Comment: Could you please provide more detailed description what are you tying to do? what is GArr, what is task()? It is better if you can show us non-working example instead of working.

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: If you have a problem with a program, then show us the program that you have a problem with (after minimising it). Don't show us another program that doesn't have a problem.